# Anylogic library dependencies

Tags: anylogic

Looking at one of my toy model, I noticed in the dependencies - Anylogic libraries that I had an older model I created.  When I remove the dependency to this model, I get an error.

- Is is possible to figure out what is needed from this older model?
- It is not clear why it is even there. The only think I can think of is that I copied/pasted an agent I wanted to reuse in my new model. But if I am correct, then I still do not understand why a dependency to the older model is required...

How to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal reason this occurs is because you have added one or more agents defined in the other model into your model (e.g., dragged agent type `A` from your other model into the `Main` of your model, creating one or more instances of agent type `A`).

The error(s) should tell you which agent type is at fault. (It could also be something like an Option List or Java Class defined in the other model.)

It may be that you had *also* copy/pasted the agent *type definition* from the other model into your model (which makes things more confusing), which is then fixable by replacing the type-from-other-model instances with type-from-my-model instances.

Comment: I have made the following experiment. I created a blank model. I copied/pasted an agent MyAgent from my older model to this new one. No problem, the dependency is not required. Now, I am copying a source using MyAgent from the older model to the new one. The dependency is now required. On the other hand, if I recreated this source from scratch in the new model, it is fine. So, it acts as if when copying the source, it does not update the reference to MyAgent in the new model. Finally, in the source, in Advanced/Agent type,  I only have MyAgent so I cannot really manually change the reference

Comment: Your experiment confirms exactly what I was saying. "I copied/pasted an agent MyAgent" means you copied the agent *type definition* to your model. When you copied "a source using MyAgent from the older model" you copied a *type definition* which embeds an *instance* of `MyAgent`.

Comment: "Finally, in the source, in Advanced/Agent type, I only have MyAgent so I cannot really manually change the reference."
Yes you can't change the type in properties; you have to delete/recreate the embedded agent (or agent population) using the correct defined-in-my-model agent type.